# iOS UITableView Custom Footer with UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, tableview

I want to make a custom footer for my UITableView.
For that, I will need the position of the last cell in the UITableView and set my UIView under the TableView.
But I don't know how to get the position of the last cell.

Is it even possible to make this kind of custom Tableview-footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a footer directly in the storyboard or xib--just drag your view so that it's *inside* your `tableView`, but *after* all of the `tableView`'s cells.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make custom footer or to know the position of your last cell. It is already available on **UITableViewDelegate**.

You need to make a custom **UIView** then on the callback of `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` return the UIView.

Example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    return view
}
```

The above code will give you a green UIView for the UITableView. Just make sure you do not set the Footer height to **0** on Storyboard or on code.

Comment: The problem here is that the footer is shown over the TableView when the TableView is longer or does not fit in the screen size. If you don't understand what I mean, I could edit my question to show you.

Comment: Sure please edit. Just a question, Do you want to have a UIView which will always be just after the UITableView always even the UITableView is scrolling? If you can share an image that will be great.